# C++ program repeating when it is supposed to terminate

Tags: c++, math, while-loop, do-while

I have been trying to make a C++ "math tutor" program. It's purpose is to ask the user if they want to do addition, subtraction, or multiplication, and once they make their selection and the calculation is complete, they are prompted to type in 0 to terminate the program and 1 to repeat it.
I tried using a do-while loop for this, but when I ran it, I found that as long as the user pressed 0 or 1, the program would repeat and it would never terminate.
Here's the code (without the math part as that really isn't relevant):

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/*
 * program to serve as math tutor for a young student
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    int repeatChoice = 0;
    //actual program has more variables here, but those are all math variables.
    
    do {
        //in this area was just code for the actual math part
        cout << "Do you want to repeat this program (0 for no, 1 for yes)?" << endl;
        cin >> repeatChoice;
        while (repeatChoice != 0 && repeatChoice != 1) {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please select 0 or 1." << endl;
            cin >> repeatChoice;
        }
        if (repeatChoice = 0)
            break;
    } while (repeatChoice = 1);

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone thinks seeing the full code will help, I'll edit the question to add it.
Please note that I'm new to programming and haven't researched any complex concepts really, so please if you can, explain it in relatively simple terms.

Comment: `if (repeatChoice = 0)` To test for equality use `==` instead. As written, it parses as an assignment `repeatChoice = 0` whose value is `0` which gets passed to `if`, and `if (0)` is never true.

Comment: ... and the `while` loop's condition will always be true, as well.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see the problem is in this part of the code:

```
...
if (repeatChoice = 0)
            break;
    } while (repeatChoice = 1);
...
```

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.